# Is it possible to use Present Perfect here?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

There is a dialog between mum and son.

Mum:Mike, there is no food in the fridge,where is it?

Mike:Sorry mum, **I've eaten all the food.**

Answer (score 1):

Sure. There is no food left - that’s the result of the action. In addition, we don’t know when exactly the food was eaten, and it’s not the point. The point is the fridge is empty. So, we’ve got every reason to use the Present Perfect.